# Different std::random_shuffle algorithms cause failing unit test on iOS simulator

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, stl

I am writing an application for the iPad using Xcode 5.0
I have tried to implement a category that will allow shuffling of an NSMutableArray. I'm using Test Driven Development, and I wrote a test like the following using Objective-C++:

```
size_t randomInteger(size_t);

@implementation ShuffleArrayTests

- (void)testsShufflesAnArray
{
    NSMutableArray* array = [@[@"one", @"two", @"three", @"four", @"five",
        @"six", @"seven", @"eight", @"nine", @"ten"] mutableCopy];

    std::vector<__unsafe_unretained id> values(array.count);
    [array getObjects:&values[0] range:NSMakeRange(0, array.count)];

    ::srandom(0);
    std::random_shuffle(values.begin(), values.end(), randomInteger);

    NSMutableArray* expectedValues =
        [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:&values[0] count:values.size()];

    ::srandom(0);
    [array shuffle];

    XCTAssertEqualObjects(expectedValues, array);
}
```

The implementation for the shuffle category method is written as follows, also in Objective-C++:

```
- (void)shuffle
{
    std::vector<__unsafe_unretained id> buffer(self.count);

    [self getObjects:&buffer[0] range:NSMakeRange(0, self.count)];

    std::random_shuffle(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), randomInteger);

    [self setArray:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:&(buffer[0])
        count:buffer.size()]];
}
```

and randomInteger is basically implemented like this:

```
size_t randomInteger(size_t limit)
{
    return ::random() % limit;
}
```

One would think that be cause the same seed value is set before performing each random shuffle that the test would pass, and the expected array would match the actual array.

The test is failing on the iOS simulator, however, and it had baffled me for many days as to why. I finally figured out that the test is calling a different version of std::random_shuffle than what is used in the category implementation. I'm not sure why this is happening.
What can be done to make the test and implementation code use the same std::random_shuffle algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you've got a logic problem in your test.

First, you create `array` and put a bunch of values into it. So far so good.

Second, you copy them into `values` and shuffle them. Still fine.

Third, you copy the elements from `values` into `expectedValues`, and shuffle *them*. OK

Finally, you expect that the contents of `array` and `expectedValues` are the same. Why do you think that this would be the case? `expectedValues` is basically `array`, shuffled twice.

If I understand what you're trying to test, I think you want to copy from `array` into `expectedValues` and shuffle that, then compare `expectedValues` and `values`.

Answer (score 0):

expectedValues is not shuffled twice. The contents of array are copied and shuffled. The results of the copied shuffle are store in expected results

The random seed is then reset so it will produce the same shuffled results and then array, which is completely independent of of expected results is shuffled, and the two arrays are compared.

I believe I found the problem. This project was originally created using Xcode 4.6 running on Mac OS X 10.7. I upgraded to Xcode 5 running on OS X 10.9, and it looks like some settings that should have been changed did not get changed. I created a new application from scratch, and put the test in that application and it passed fine. I was then able to look at the differences between the project.

For the application itself I found that in the build settings under **Apple LLVM 5.0 - Language - C++**, the **C++ Standard Library** was set to **Compiler Default**; I changed it to **libc++ (LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support)** and that appears to fix the issue.